# Overriding adb package body from a with-ed .gpr project

Tags: build-process, ada, gnat

I'm using GNAT gprbuild.

I have a project file, **A.gpr** that withs project file **B.gpr** .

There is the possibility that the **B.gpr** project file  could be a few **with-ed** levels deep from **A.gpr**

**B.gpr** has source files **X.adb** and **X.ads** .

**A.gpr** defines a main file **Y.adb** that withs **X.ads**

Its a requirement that **A.gpr** must with **B.gpr**.

By only extending or editing **A.gpr**  I would like to use a different **X.adb** .

How do i do this?

The closest thing I have found so far is https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Project-Extension.html.

However I keep hitting the error:

```
unit "X" cannot belong to several projects

project "A" {overriding X.adb file path}

unit "X" already belongs to project "B" 

project "B" {original x.adb filepath}
```

Comment: I doubt that this is possible.

Comment: There’s no problem if B is only one level down. But if there’s an intermediate project C which also withs B, which `x.adb` is C going to use? You may find some answers in the GPRBuild User Guide, e.g. http://docs.adacore.com/gprbuild-docs/html/share/gnat_project_manager.html#project-hierarchy-extension

Comment: Why can you **only** edit A.gpr? If you could edit / rearrange the code it would be easy...

Answer (score 0):

If files (in this case different x.adb) are in different directories it is possible by use of case statement.
For example in some of my gpr files I have following lines:

```
  type OS_Type is ("Unix", "Windows");
  OS: OS_Type := external ("OS", "Unix");

  case OS is
  when "Unix"    =>
    for Source_Dirs use ("src", "src/unix");
  when "Windows" =>
    for Source_Dirs use ("src", "src/windows");
  end case;
```

As you can see, depending on variable different source directories are used.

(OS defaults to "Unix", to set variable you add
`-Xvariable=value` to you gprbuild call [which in this example would be
`-XOS=Windows`]).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that uses both paths and body-selection based on project variables:

```
project Example is

   for Object_Dir use "obj";
   for Exec_Dir use ".";
   type Language_Type is
      ("Spanish", "English");
   Language : Language_Type := external ("Language", "English");
   for Source_Dirs use ("src", "src/" & Language);
   for Main use ("testbed.adb");
   type Starts_Week_Type is
      ("mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun");
   Starts_Week : Starts_Week_Type := external ("Starts_Week", "sun");

   package Ide is
      for Documentation_Dir use "doc";
   end Ide;

   package Prove is
      for Switches use ("-j4");
   end Prove;

   package Builder is
      for Default_Switches ("ada") use ("-j4", "-C", "-g");
   end Builder;

   package Compiler is
      for Default_Switches ("ada") use
        ("-gnato", "-fstack-check", "-gnatE", "-gnata", "-gnat12", "-g", "-gnatf");
   end Compiler;

   package Binder is
      for Default_Switches ("ada") use ("-shared");
   end Binder;

   package Linker is
      for Default_Switches ("ada") use ("-g");
   end Linker;

   package Naming is
      for Specification("Example.Types.Week") use
        "Example-types-"&Starts_Week&"_week.ada";
   end Naming;

end Example;
```

As you can see the line `for Source_Dirs use ("src", "src/" & Language);` makes the `src` and either `src/English` or `src/Spanish` the directories that will be searched/used when looking for source files.

Later, in Naming, we have a file whose name is dependent on a project variable being selected as the body of the indicated file. -- Namely the file `types-XXX_week.ada` where `XXX` is one of the three-letter day-abbreviations the `Starts_Week` scenario-variable may take.